# Why do android studio docs appear to be inaccurate for starting a project?

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic2

I have a cordova/ionic project that I'm trying to run in Android Studio on Mac OS. However, I don't even see the AVD Manager toolbar button or the Tools > Android > AVD Manager menu option mentioned in the docs. Also, building doesn't seem to do anything either. Finally, when I start a new blank Android project the docs suggest I will be able to enter the company and domain name in the wizard but I am never prompted for that--only a project name and type.

Am I just missing an SDK? I've tried setting the ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME and PATH as suggested [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/). Nothing changes. Oddly, I don't remember running into this on my previous Mac.

Note that I can build the project successfully from terminal with the ionic/cordova tools.

Comment: On the "Tools > Android > ADB Manager menu option", This is a dynamic menu, which only appears AFTER the gradle sync process has finished (and is appropriate to the project). You just need a good tutorial or play with it until you get the idea of how it works. It tells you when things are missing (it's quite good at that). A bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Thanks @JonGoodwin but I think I'm still missing something major beyond that. I don't even have the Tools > Android menu. I confirmed that this is all working with same version of Android Studio (2.3.3) on my old machine. Would have thought I was missing the Android SDK but I can't even get to the SDK manager.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem stemmed from having JDK 8 installed. After reading that google recommends using the JDK included with Android Studio I completely removed the standalone JDK installation and Android Studio, then reinstalled Studio. Now it works as described in the docs.

If anyone can provide a more specific reason for this I'll happily flag it as the answer.